# ADF Required Message Not show at first time

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm facing bug when go to page at first time. But if i refresh again the page, the required message working fine
I set the **require** for **af:inputText**

revision: i set showRequired="<strike>false</strike> true"

```
<af:inputText id="id" styleClass="input-medium" showRequired="true"
                required="true"
                requiredMessageDetail="You Must Insert ID"
                maximumLength="50" autoSubmit="true" simple="true"
                contentStyle="width:25%;"/>
```

I check **console** in **Chrome** got error like this:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. message-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:162
AdfDhtmlMessagesPeer._messageUpdate message-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:162
AdfDhtmlMessagesPeer.MessageNotify message-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:106
AdfRichUIPeer.messageNotify core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:15213
AdfDhtmlPage._notifyComponent boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:10917
AdfDhtmlPage.addMessage boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:10705
AdfUIEditableValue._addFacesMessage core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:5417
AdfUIEditableValue._addRequiredFacesMessage core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:5411
AdfUIEditableValue.ValidateValue core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:5370
AdfUIEditableValue.validate core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:5295
AdfDhtmlPage._processValidators boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:7551
AdfDhtmlPage.queueEvent boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:7379
AdfUIComponent.queueEvent core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:4265
AdfComponentEvent.queue boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:2155
AdfDhtmlCommandLinkPeer.HandleComponentClick core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:18885
AdfRichUIPeer.DispatchComponentEvent core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:15124
AdfUIComponent._deliverEvent core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:4356
AdfUIComponent.broadcast core-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:4282
AdfDhtmlPage._deliverQueuedEvents boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:7622
AdfDhtmlPage._deliverAllQueuedEvents boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:7604
AdfDhtmlPage._eventLoopDeliverEvents boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:7595
AdfDhtmlPage._redistribute boot-11.1.1.5.0-1095.js:8591
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: Which version of ADF do you use?

Comment: i don't know where the ADF version, i check about in jdev is:
About
-----

Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1 11.1.1.5.0
Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.5.0
Build JDEVADF_11.1.1.5.0_GENERIC_110409.0025.6013
Copyright © 1997, 2011 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
IDE Version: 11.1.1.5.37.60.13
Product ID: oracle.jdeveloper
Product Version: 11.1.1.5.37.60.13

Version
-------

Component Version
========= =======
ADF Business Components 11.1.1.60.13
Java(TM) Platform 1.6.0_24
Oracle IDE 11.1.1.5.37.60.13
Versioning Support 11.1.1.5.37.60.13

Comment: this one? : ADF Business Components 11.1.1.60.13

Comment: This happens when you submit the form? You try to submit the form without filling this required field and the "Required Message" does not show up? Tell me the exact procedure please

Comment: @AlbanoVito yes, i have some input text, and 2 input text set to required. And i have button submit, then i click the button submit, the "Required Message" doesn't show, but the red color in input text show

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this and works very well.

```
<af:form id="f1">
        <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
            <f:facet name="center">
                <!-- id="af_one_column_stretched"   -->
                <af:panelGroupLayout layout="scroll" id="pgl1">
                    <af:inputText id="id" styleClass="input-medium" showRequired="false" required="true"
                                  requiredMessageDetail="You Must Insert ID" maximumLength="50" autoSubmit="true"
                                  simple="true" contentStyle="width:25%;" label="Input"/>
                    <af:commandButton text="Submit" id="cb1"/>
                </af:panelGroupLayout>
            </f:facet>
        </af:panelStretchLayout>
    </af:form>
```

Maybe you have inserted it within some other elements that cause that behavior. Try this and then you may figure out the real problem. 
Tung

Comment: sorry, i set showRequired="true" not false, i try embed your code, still not working.

Comment: i try to inspect every element. In my page i include xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" and  have tag <f: for display data <af:table using <f:facet . I try to remove <f: and xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" then it's work. is there incompatible tag <f: in adf?

Comment: Maybe there is, you have to try something more on your own, glad you made it to work!

Answer (score 0):

my answer for this bug, there is incompatible when include `xmlns:f="java.sun.com/jsf/core"` and tag `<f:`
for display data  `<af:table` using `<f:facet`.

Try to remove `<f:` and  `xmlns:f="java.sun.com/jsf/core"`, then it's work.